# Add only new records in MySQL via script

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, optimization, query-optimization

I have a large database which I am trying to update via perl.  The information to be added comes from a csv file which I do not control (but which is trusted—it comes from a different part of our company). For each record in the file, I need to either add it (if it does not exist) or do nothing (if it exists). Adding a record consists of the usual `INSERT INTO`, but before that can run for a particular entry a specific `UPDATE` must be run.

Let's say for the sake of concreteness that the file has 10,000 entries, but 90% of them are already in the database. What is the most efficient way to import the records? I can see a few obvious approaches:

- Pull all records of this type from the database, then check each of the entries from the file for membership. Downside: lots of data transfer, possibly enough to time the server out.
- Read in the entries from the file and send a query for just those records with an `RLIKE 'foo|bar|baz|...'` query (or a `stuff = 'foo' || stuff = 'bar' || ...` query, but that seems even worse). Downside: huge query, probably enough to choke the server.
- Read in the file, send a query for each entry, then add it if appropriate. Downside: tens of thousands of queries, very slow.

Apart from the `UPDATE` requirement, this seems like a fairly standard issue that presumably has a standard solution. If there is, it can probably be adapted to my case with appropriate use of tests on the `auto_increment` primary key.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution is to use `INSERT IGNORE` which won't raise an error if the insertion would fail because of a constraint. This isn't much use to you as it doesn't give you a chance to do the `UPDATE` before you know the `INSERT` is going to work. If you can do the update afterwards, however, this is ideal: just `INSERT IGNORE` each record and then do the `UPDATE` if it succeeded.

If a record *already exists* that means a record with a matching unique key is already in the database, so I don't understand the `RLIKE` proposal which is bound to be slow.

I would use Perl to grep the CSV file using `SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE key = ?` for each record, and removing anything where the result is non-zero.

Then just do your `UPDATE` and `INSERT` for everything left in the filtered CSV data.

Comment: None of the fields I'm entering are primary keys, though. The primary key is the `auto_increment` field I mentioned. So `UPDATE IGNORE` doesn't work.

Comment: If there is a record matching the fields I am inserting. So if I have `INSERT INTO tbl (foo, bar, baz) VALUES ('f', 'b', 'b')` I don't want to add the record if there is an entry with foo='f', bar='b', and baz='b'.

Comment: @Charles: then I would `ALTER TABLE tbl ADD UNIQUE INDEX (foo, bar, baz)` and then `INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl`.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option: the database is used by a (large) external application that requires the table is laid out as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to timeout the server if you keep flushing data while iterating the list.